# Why no other constructor is being allowed?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I am learning about **initializer list** and learnt that const members must be initialized using it, because you cannot initialize it using default constructor or parameterised constructor.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    const int y;            
public:         
    Foo(int yy) :y(yy){}        
    int getY();
};
```

Now suppose if I have another member `int x;` **not a const,Why can't I initialize it using default constructor**, What is the idea behind this restriction?

The code that gives error:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    const int y;    
    int x;
public:     
    Foo(int yy) :y(yy){}
    Foo()
    {
        x = 100;
    }
    int getY();
};
```

Comment: "_Why can't I initialize it using default constructor_" Yes you can? Can you be a bit more clear?

Comment: You can initialize any member you like in your default constructor. I don't understand the question. Please post a MCVE for what you think does *not* work.

Comment: Btw, *"because you cannot initialize it using default constructor or parameterised constructor."* sounds like you have a misunderstanding about the term "default constructor".

Comment: Good job with the mcve. I've added a response to my answer that describes the problem with your code.

Comment: You probably haven't covered this in your book/course yet, but there's an indirect way as well. One constructor may _delegate_ to another constructor, instead of having an initializer list. The `const` members must then be initialized by the second, delegated-to constructor.

Answer (score 4):

> I am learning about initializer list and learnt that const members must be initialized using it, because you cannot initialize it using default constructor or parameterised constructor.

Const members can be initialized in the member initializer list of both a default constructor and any parametrised constructor. (A default constructor is a constructor that can be invoked without parameters.)

> Now suppose if I have another member int x; not a const,Why can't I initialize it using default constructor, What is the idea behind this restriction?

You can initialize any number of members (there is probably some implementation defined limit, but it's not relevant to this question) in the default constructor. There is no such restriction that you describe.

Demo, class with two members, both initialized in the default constructor:

```
struct Foo {
    const int y;
    int       x;
    Foo(): y(1), x(100){}
};
```

---

Edit for the mcve.

> The code that gives error:
>
> ```
> class Foo
> {
> private:
>     const int y;    
>     int x;
> public:     
>     Foo(int yy) :y(yy){}
>     Foo()
>     {
>         x = 100;
>     }
>     int getY();
> };
> ```

*All* constructors must initialize const members. Your parametrised constructor does initialize `y`, but the default constructor doesn't. That is why it doesn't work. See my demo above for a working example.

PS. Your parametrised constructor doesn't initialize `x`, but that is OK: `x` isn't const, so you can assign a value to it later.

---

> In my code if I have a parameterised constructor like Foo(int xx) { x = xx;}
>
> It will not give any error

This program:

```
struct Foo {
    const int y;
    int       x;
    Foo(int xx) { x = xx;}
};
```

Is ill formed in standard C++. If your compiler accepts it without a warning, then it isn't standard compliant.

Comment: *"there is probably some implementation defined limit, but it's not relevant to this question"* Fun fact of the day: Annex B of C++14 recommends this limit to be at least 6144.

Comment: When you say that All constructors must initialize const members.

Comment: In my code if I have a parameterised constructor  like Foo(int xx) { x = xx;}

Comment: It will not give any error and you said all constructors must initialize const members.

Comment: @SumeetSingh Nope, the answer is completely correct at that. Every `const` built-in variable needs to be initialized in every constructor. If you think that does not happen for you, new question with MCVE please.

Answer (score 1):

Unclear what you're trying to accomplish.
Following code simply compiles

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int _nonConst;
    const int _const;

public:
    Foo() : _const(10), _nonConst(11)
    {

    }

    Foo(int x) : _const(x), _nonConst(x)
    {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood the question properly. To summarize what you can and can't do:

```
// .h
class MyClass
{
private:
    int x;
    const int y;

public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(int initValue);
};

// .cpp
// The following is legal
MyClass::MyClass() 
: x(0), y(0) 
{}     

// Alternatively, the following is legal too. 
MyClass::MyClass() 
: y(0) 
{ 
    x = 0; 
}   

// This is not legal: y cannot be initialized that way as it is const.
// No problem for x though.
MyClass::MyClass() 
{ 
    x = 0; 
    y = 0; // You cannot do that
} 

// The following is legal
MyClass::MyClass(int initValue) 
: x(initValue), y(initValue) 
{}     

// Alternatively, the following is legal too. 
MyClass::MyClass(int initValue) 
: y(initValue) 
{ 
    x = initValue; 
}   

// This is not legal: y cannot be initialized that way as it is const.
// No problem for x though.
MyClass::MyClass(int initValue) 
{ 
    x = initValue; 
    y = initValue; // You cannot do that
}
```

Of course, you can only have one CTor per declared signature. The examples above are 3 alternatives - 2 legal and 1 illegal - per declared signature.